# Remote Debug ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, remote-debugging

Is there a way to remotely debug an ASP.Net website (not a web application). One problem I see is that no pdb files are create even in debug.

I know about remote debugger and have used it with no problem in web applications and windows services, but cant seem to get it to work whit web sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to build in debug with visualstudio and then deploy those .pdb files to your remote iis bin folder.

Check also that remote web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```